# MS Teams : We couldn't save your tab settings. Please try again

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

I am trying to add a configuration tab in Teams as shown in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration But I am getting Error as We couldn't save your tab settings. Please try again.

Below is the Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
microsoftTeams.initialize();
microsoftTeams.settings.registerOnSaveHandler(function (saveEvent) {
var radios = document.getElementsByName("maptype");
if (radios[0].checked) {
   microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
     entityId: "bing",
     contentUrl: "https://www.bing.com/maps/embed",
     suggestedDisplayName: "Bing Map",
     websiteUrl: "https://www.bing.com/maps",
     removeUrl: "https://teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net/tabremove.html",
  });
}
else {
   microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
     entityId: "google",
     contentUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps/embed",
     suggestedDisplayName: "Google Map",
     websiteUrl: "https://www.google.com/maps",
     removeUrl: "https://teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net/tabremove.html",
  });
}

saveEvent.notifySuccess();
});

function onClick() {
microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
}
</script>
```

[Here is the Error image in MS Teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNeFv.png)

Comment: Did you add ***.bing.com** and ***.google.com** as part of validDomains in manifest file? 
If your tab configuration or content UI needs to navigate to any other domain besides the one use for tab configuration, that domain must be specified validDomain.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I did add it as valid domains                                               
    "validDomains": [
    "static2.sharepointonline.com",
    "secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com",
    "code.jquery.com",
    "statics.teams.microsoft.com",
    "*.microsoftonline.com",
    "ajax.googleapis.com",
    "*.bing.com",
    "*.google.com"
  ]

Comment: Please add "teams-get-started-sample.azurewebsites.net" as part of validDomains. Also change _**.bing.com**_  to ***.bing.com** or **bing.com**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Wajeed-MSTF suggested add Valid domains as blow solved my problem. Thank You!

```
 "validDomains": [ "static2.sharepointonline.com", "secure.aadcdn.microsoftonline-p.com", "code.jquery.com", "statics.teams.microsoft.com", ".microsoftonline.com", "ajax.googleapis.com", ".bing.com", "*.google.com" ]
```